# Compare errors in Chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, assert, chai

I needed to implement my own error class in ES6 (with node v4):

```
class QueryObjectError {
    constructor (message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

I have a portion of code that throws said error type:

```
function myFunct () {
    throw new QueryObjectError('a message');
}
```

And I am using Mocha and Chai to test the the function throws the expected error with the expected message:

```
it('is a test', function (done) {
    var err = new QueryObjectError('abc');
    assert.throw(myFunct, err);
    done();
});
```

The test passes although the `QueryObjectError` objects have different messages and I want to test the case in which deep equality is checked. Any way to solve this with the given tools?

Comment: Is this any different in ES5?

Comment: ES5 does not support classes defined like in the example, so I guess yes

Comment: No, your `class` is no different from `function QueryObjectError(message) { this.message = message; }`. The syntax is mostly sugar.

Comment: In theory yes, but since I'm letting node do the translation and I don't have it in a separate file, I prefer assuming I don't know what happens. At any rate I have replaced the class example with your function equivalent and indeed the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two salient issues with your code:

1. You do not use `assert.throw` correctly. You should pass the constructor to the expected exception as the 2nd argument and a regular expression or a string as the 3rd argument. If the 3rd argument is a string, Chai will check that the string exist in the exception's message. If it is a regular expression, it will test whether the message is matched by the expression.
2. Your exception should have a `toString` method that returns the message, otherwise Chai won't know how to check the message.

Here is an example showing a failure and a success:

```
import { assert } from "chai";

class QueryObjectError {
    constructor (message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    toString() {
        return this.message;
    }
}

function myFunct () {
    throw new QueryObjectError('a message');
}

it('is a test', function () {
    assert.throw(myFunct, QueryObjectError, 'abc');
});

it('is another test', function () {
    assert.throw(myFunct, QueryObjectError, /^a message$/);
});
```